# Change Oracle-query to work with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle

In **Oracle** I could to run the query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT TABLE1_ID_SQ.nextval,
       'Ivan',
       'Ivanoff',
       1,
       TABLE1_RV_SQ.nextval,
       'user_010',
       SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM TABLE1
                 WHERE NAME = 'Ivan'
                   AND LASTNAME= 'Ivanoff'
                   AND ACTIVE = 1);
```

Now I try to update it, to work with **Postgres**. I try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT nextval(table1_id_sq),
       'Ivan',
       'Ivanoff',
       true,
       nextval(table1_rv_sq),
       'user_010',
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE name= 'Ivan'
                   AND lastname = 'Ivanoff'
                   AND active = true);
```

But it does not work! I now have **error: "column table1_id_sq does not exist"**.
Can you help me, and say, where I did a mistake? ))

Comment: Name of the sequence must be between single quotes ' , see also the fine manual:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html